# Preload relation into already fetched model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models namely: `organization`, `base_url` and `ldap_group_permission`. `organization` has a one to many relationship with `base_url` which also has same with `ldap_group_permission`. There is already a variable holding a fetched record of an organization model named `current_organization`.

I can obviously do `current_organization.base_urls` to get the base_urls for the organization; but the problem lies at the point where I also need the `ldap_group_permission` for each of the base_urls. I can decide to run a loop through each base_url but that will be creating the N+1 query problem and each base_url running individual queries in the database which will slow down performance.

How do I do I fetch `current_organization`'s base_urls while also getting the ldap_group_permissions together in one query?

Comment: https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `current_organization` with eager loading associated records like this

```rb
current_organization = Organization.includes(base_urls: :ldap_group_permissions).find(id)
```

And then enumerate

```rb
current_organization.base_urls.each do |base_url|
  base_url.ldap_group_permissions.each do |ldap_group_permission|
    # Access every ldap_group_permission
  end
end
```

This way you will avoid N+1

Comment: is there a way I can dump and see all the data retrieved please?

Comment: It's better to create new question. As I understand you need `map`